# Not displaying Duplicates

Tags: sql, duplicates

I have results displaying duplicates that I don't want. We have a column call addresstypes and it returns a B or L depending on what was entered in db. It was incorrect to enter data if B was chosen as this was both delivery and legal address.

When pulling data, I get serial numbers etc but I get some twice...the ones that have address data in both B & L.

Here is my query - how can I make the double row not display?

```
USE inventory
SELECT distinct
dbo.addressinfo.locationinfoid, dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent.serialnum,    dbo.addressinfo.addresstype
FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent
full join dbo.addressinfo
on  dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent.locationinfoid = dbo.addressinfo.locationinfoid
where  (clientName = 'cps lease')
and (locationtype = 'merchant')
and (addresstype = 'b' or addresstype = 'l')
order by serialnum
```

Sample of results

```
locationinfoid  serialnum
2887540       301-252-800   B
2887540       301-252-800   L
```

Comment: If you want to get distinct `locationinfoid` then, Which `serialnum` and `addresstype` do you want to display from the duplicated rows for each `locationinfoid`??

Comment: They don't look like duplicates. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: it doesn't matter for this report, just not both

Comment: they are the same locationinfoid and serialnum...I only one either

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720830/how-to-select-distinct-in-sql-server-2008-but-for-only-one-field-out-of-many

Answer (score 1):

As per your comment, since it doesn't matter which values of `addresstype` do you want to select for each `locationinfoid`, use a `GROUP BY locationinfoid, serialnum` with `MAX`:

```
SELECT
  a.locationinfoid, 
  e.serialnum, 
  MAX(a.addresstype)
FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent AS e
full join dbo.addressinfo AS a on e.locationinfoid = a.locationinfoid
where clientName = 'cps lease'
 and locationtype = 'merchant'
 and addresstype = 'b' or addresstype = 'l'
GROUP BY a.locationinfoid, e.serialnum
order by serialnum;
```

This will give you distinct values of `locationinfoid`.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct returns any distinct records over *any* column that is included in the select list. So if you have different values for `addressinfo.locationinfoid`, `serialnum` or `addressinfo.addresstype` then you're going to get duplicate records

In this case it looks like you're pulling in two different `addresstypes` so you will get 2 "duplicate" records if a `locationinfoid` and `serialnum` pair have one of each. Your edit to include the return values confirms this.

If you don't care about the `addresstype` then don't include it in the select list. Try:

```
USE inventory
SELECT distinct
dbo.addressinfo.locationinfoid, dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent.serialnum
FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent
full join dbo.addressinfo
on  dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent.locationinfoid = dbo.addressinfo.locationinfoid
where  (clientName = 'cps lease')
and (locationtype = 'merchant')
and (addresstype = 'b' or addresstype = 'l')
order by serialnum
```

Answer (score 0):

You have many options,

- Exclude the Address Type from your result and use distinct
- use an aggregate funciton and group by function
- Make an Intersect Union of your clausules ofr knowing the duplicates

If you don't want to fetch the address type and you wanna know the duplicates, I would rewrite the query in this way:

```
SELECT     A.locationinfoid, E.serialnum
FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent E
inner join dbo.addressinfo A
on  E.locationinfoid = A.locationinfoid
where  (clientName = 'cps lease')
and (locationtype = 'merchant')
and (addresstype = 'b')
order by serialnum

INTERSECT

SELECT     A.locationinfoid, E.serialnum
FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent E
inner join dbo.addressinfo A
on  E.locationinfoid = A.locationinfoid
where  (clientName = 'cps lease')
and (locationtype = 'merchant')
and (addresstype = 'L')
order by serialnum
```

If you just want to fetch them all don't include the AddressType in your select using distinct

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT   A.locationinfoid, E.serialnum
    FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent E
    FULL join dbo.addressinfo A
    on  E.locationinfoid = A.locationinfoid
    where  (clientName = 'cps lease')
    and (locationtype = 'merchant')
    and (addresstype IN('b', 'l'))
    order by serialnum
```

Also you can use an aggregate function like MAX, or MIN to your clausule, this way you dont need to use your distinct clausule

```
SELECT  A.locationinfoid, E.serialnum, MAX(A.addresstype ) AS addresstype 
        FROM dbo.equipmentlocationscurrent E
        FULL join dbo.addressinfo A
        on  E.locationinfoid = A.locationinfoid
        where  (clientName = 'cps lease')
        and (locationtype = 'merchant')
        and (addresstype IN('b', 'l'))
        Group by  A.locationinfoid, E.serialnum
        order by serialnum
```